Checking for bad blocks with smartctl or other means in RAID arrays
My aim is setting up a script that periodically checks disks in a RAID 1 and in a RAID 5 arrays and possibly sends an alert when a disk goes offline. I thought the option -H of smartctl was suitable for the case - isn't it? - and anyway I've just discovered I can get an explicit information about the status of the disks with the following command.
storcli /c0/v0 show all

Of course with in the output of suche a command I have to count how many disks and in the "Onln" status with a "grep -c".
Anyway in the past - https://serverfault.com/questions/1152562/the-bare-minimum-smartctl-command-to-check-disk-health -  I've been warned about the importance of checking also whether some bad sector appeared.
I've read the discussion at the URL below, but I'm still confused, I still don't know what command am I supposed to use.
How to check entire hard disk for errors and bad sectors
Thanks in advance!
Andrea

If you need to use storcli to access the disks in the MegaRAID then you'll not be able to use smartctl directly. As you suggest, you're going to need to parse the output of the command that implements "list the status of the disks, one by one"

Chris, actually I'm confused and I don't know if I have to necessarily use storcli instead of smartctl. Why couldn't I use both of them? The information I would get from storcli is "how many disks are online", so that if the total number is less than the total number of disks in use, then I would send a notification. But I suspect for this a "smartctl -H" would be enough, though that way the result would be expressed in terms of "SMART overall-health self-assessment test result" (possibly "PASSED") for SATA disks and in terms of "SMART Health Status" (possibly "OK") for SAS disks.

What I wish to know is wheter a disk has to be replaced for any reason, including a possibly unacceptable increase of bad sectors. Anyway I still couldn't find the way to perform checks on the possible presence of bad sectors. Thanks!

Last time I had a server with an LSI MedaRAID card I couldn't reach the physical disks with smartctl. Instead I had to use storcli. If the physical disks underlying your RAID really are exposed on your system then smartctl should be fine. But beware of trying to use smartctl on the virtualised disk(s) presented through the RAID card

Chris, with smartctl I can see information for every physical disk underlying the RAID arrays, though I still don't know for sure whether "smartctl -H" is enough to verify that every physical disk is "online" and still I don't know how to prevent failures due to bad sectors. Anyway I'm not sure I got what you mean with "virtualised disk(s) presented through the RAID card". I'm interested in the health of the physical disks. Thanks!
